# What is Princess Peach's protection super effect and what does it do?

Tags: mario-plus-rabbids-kingdom-battle

What does the protection super effect do? I am wondering if this lowers Peach's health when enemies hit someone not Peach because of protection because I see Valkyries use it and there health for both valkyries lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Reno Gazette Journal,](https://www.rgj.com/story/life/2017/08/29/mario-rabbids-kingdom-battle-guide-weapons-abilities-technobubble/610534001/) (Google publicly known as RGJ), here is what Princess Peach's **Protection** ability can do:

> Protection: Princess Peach ain’t all about attacking. This skill splits damage and distributes it among team members so the original target of an attack doesn’t have to bear its brunt solo.

In short words, Princess Peach's protection ability lowers damage from enemy attacks.

Comment: My pain? No, *our* pain.

Comment: Can you upgrade to 100% so 2 of your teammates does not get hit.